# How can i train model on additional classes without retraining on previous class in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, transfer-learning

How I can train my face recognition system on new personalities (classes) without retraining the model on old personalities (old classes)?

I load google's pretrained model Resnet v1 in order to train system to recognize faces of personalities and in result I get a classifier that can classify trained personalities. Problem is that when I want to train them on a new person's face either I have to train the model on both old person's and new person, what I want is to train the model on new person without losing the training on old person's

```
import argparse
import logging
import os
import pickle
import sys
import time

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile

from lfw_input import filter_dataset, split_dataset, get_dataset
from medium_facenet_tutorial import lfw_input

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def main(input_directory, model_path, classifier_output_path, batch_size, num_threads, num_epochs,
         min_images_per_labels, split_ratio, is_train=True):
    """
    Loads images from :param input_dir, creates embeddings using a model defined at :param model_path, and trains
     a classifier outputted to :param output_path

    :param input_directory: Path to directory containing pre-processed images
    :param model_path: Path to protobuf graph file for facenet model
    :param classifier_output_path: Path to write pickled classifier
    :param batch_size: Batch size to create embeddings
    :param num_threads: Number of threads to utilize for queuing
    :param num_epochs: Number of epochs for each image
    :param min_images_per_labels: Minimum number of images per class
    :param split_ratio: Ratio to split train/test dataset
    :param is_train: bool denoting if training or evaluate
    """

    start_time = time.time()
    with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=False)) as sess:
        train_set, test_set = _get_test_and_train_set(input_directory, min_num_images_per_label=min_images_per_labels,
                                                      split_ratio=split_ratio)
        if is_train:
            images, labels, class_names = _load_images_and_labels(train_set, image_size=160, batch_size=batch_size,
                                                                  num_threads=num_threads, num_epochs=num_epochs,
                                                                  random_flip=True, random_brightness=True,
                                                                  random_contrast=True)
        else:
            images, labels, class_names = _load_images_and_labels(test_set, image_size=160, batch_size=batch_size,
                                                                  num_threads=num_threads, num_epochs=1)

        _load_model(model_filepath=model_path)

        init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
        sess.run(init_op)

        images_placeholder = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("input:0")
        embedding_layer = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("embeddings:0")
        phase_train_placeholder = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("phase_train:0")

        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord, sess=sess)

        emb_array, label_array = _create_embeddings(embedding_layer, images, labels, images_placeholder,
                                                    phase_train_placeholder, sess)

        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads=threads)
        logger.info('Created {} embeddings'.format(len(emb_array)))

        classifier_filename = classifier_output_path

        if is_train:
            _train_and_save_classifier(emb_array, label_array, class_names, classifier_filename)
        else:
            _evaluate_classifier(emb_array, label_array, classifier_filename)

        logger.info('Completed in {} seconds'.format(time.time() - start_time))


def _get_test_and_train_set(input_dir, min_num_images_per_label, split_ratio=0.7):
    """
    Load train and test dataset. Classes with < :param min_num_images_per_label will be filtered out.
    :param input_dir: 
    :param min_num_images_per_label: 
    :param split_ratio: 
    :return: 
    """
    dataset = get_dataset(input_dir)
    dataset = filter_dataset(dataset, min_images_per_label=min_num_images_per_label)
    train_set, test_set = split_dataset(dataset, split_ratio=split_ratio)

    return train_set, test_set


def _load_images_and_labels(dataset, image_size, batch_size, num_threads, num_epochs, random_flip=False,
                            random_brightness=False, random_contrast=False):
    class_names = [cls.name for cls in dataset]
    image_paths, labels = lfw_input.get_image_paths_and_labels(dataset)
    images, labels = lfw_input.read_data(image_paths, labels, image_size, batch_size, num_epochs, num_threads,
                                         shuffle=False, random_flip=random_flip, random_brightness=random_brightness,
                                         random_contrast=random_contrast)
    return images, labels, class_names


def _load_model(model_filepath):
    """
    Load frozen protobuf graph
    :param model_filepath: Path to protobuf graph
    :type model_filepath: str
    """
    model_exp = os.path.expanduser(model_filepath)
    if os.path.isfile(model_exp):
        logging.info('Model filename: %s' % model_exp)
        with gfile.FastGFile(model_exp, 'rb') as f:
            graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
            graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
            tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
    else:
        logger.error('Missing model file. Exiting')
        sys.exit(-1)


def _create_embeddings(embedding_layer, images, labels, images_placeholder, phase_train_placeholder, sess):
    """
    Uses model to generate embeddings from :param images.
    :param embedding_layer: 
    :param images: 
    :param labels: 
    :param images_placeholder: 
    :param phase_train_placeholder: 
    :param sess: 
    :return: (tuple): image embeddings and labels
    """
    emb_array = None
    label_array = None
    try:
        i = 0
        while True:
            batch_images, batch_labels = sess.run([images, labels])
            logger.info('Processing iteration {} batch of size: {}'.format(i, len(batch_labels)))
            emb = sess.run(embedding_layer,
                           feed_dict={images_placeholder: batch_images, phase_train_placeholder: False})

            emb_array = np.concatenate([emb_array, emb]) if emb_array is not None else emb
            label_array = np.concatenate([label_array, batch_labels]) if label_array is not None else batch_labels
            i += 1

    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        pass

    return emb_array, label_array


def _train_and_save_classifier(emb_array, label_array, class_names, classifier_filename_exp):
    logger.info('Training Classifier')
    model = SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True, verbose=False)
    model.fit(emb_array, label_array)

    with open(classifier_filename_exp, 'wb') as outfile:
        pickle.dump((model, class_names), outfile)
    logging.info('Saved classifier model to file "%s"' % classifier_filename_exp)


def _evaluate_classifier(emb_array, label_array, classifier_filename):
    logger.info('Evaluating classifier on {} images'.format(len(emb_array)))
    if not os.path.exists(classifier_filename):
        raise ValueError('Pickled classifier not found, have you trained first?')

    with open(classifier_filename, 'rb') as f:
        model, class_names = pickle.load(f)

        predictions = model.predict_proba(emb_array, )
        best_class_indices = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
        best_class_probabilities = predictions[np.arange(len(best_class_indices)), best_class_indices]

        for i in range(len(best_class_indices)):
            print('%4d  %s: %.3f' % (i, class_names[best_class_indices[i]], best_class_probabilities[i]))

        accuracy = np.mean(np.equal(best_class_indices, label_array))
        print('Accuracy: %.3f' % accuracy)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=True)
    parser.add_argument('--model-path', type=str, action='store', dest='model_path',
                        help='Path to model protobuf graph')
    parser.add_argument('--input-dir', type=str, action='store', dest='input_dir',
                        help='Input path of data to train on')
    parser.add_argument('--batch-size', type=int, action='store', dest='batch_size',
                        help='Input path of data to train on', default=128)
    parser.add_argument('--num-threads', type=int, action='store', dest='num_threads', default=16,
                        help='Number of threads to utilize for queue')
    parser.add_argument('--num-epochs', type=int, action='store', dest='num_epochs', default=3,
                        help='Path to output trained classifier model')
    parser.add_argument('--split-ratio', type=float, action='store', dest='split_ratio', default=0.7,
                        help='Ratio to split train/test dataset')
    parser.add_argument('--min-num-images-per-class', type=int, action='store', default=10,
                        dest='min_images_per_class', help='Minimum number of images per class')
    parser.add_argument('--classifier-path', type=str, action='store', dest='classifier_path',
                        help='Path to output trained classifier model')
    parser.add_argument('--is-train', action='store_true', dest='is_train', default=False,
                        help='Flag to determine if train or evaluate')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    main(input_directory=args.input_dir, model_path=args.model_path, classifier_output_path=args.classifier_path,
         batch_size=args.batch_size, num_threads=args.num_threads, num_epochs=args.num_epochs,
         min_images_per_labels=args.min_images_per_class, split_ratio=args.split_ratio, is_train=args.is_train)
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: This is not possible.

The reason for this is that if you want to change the set of labels (in your case the set of faces) your neural network classifies, you have to at least replace your output layer (giving the probability distribution over your labels).
Since introducing a new label, changes the probability of all labels (since they are normalised) you have to retrain your output layer (and probably also the other layers) with training samples of the new and the old labels/faces.